# Java GUI panel revalidation

Tags: java, user-interface, repaint

I am having a main class which controls all the application, including the displaying of all the panels. The method to display the main application panel is:

```
private void displayMainApplicationPanel() {
  String[] columnNames = { "Media ID", "Title", "Pricipal Actors", "Type", "Duration", "Launch Date", "Price",
    "Status" };
ResultSet resultSet = databaseLogicController.showMediaInfo();
String[][] data = parseMediaResultSet(resultSet, 8);

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

  @Override
  public void run() {
    graphicController.showMainApplicationPanel(data, columnNames);
    addMainApplicationPanelSearchButtonActionListener();
    addMainApplicationPanelSearchTextFieldKeyListener();
    addMainApplicationPanelShowMyIdButtonActionListener();
    addMainApplicationPanelBorrowMediaButtonActionListener();
    addMainApplicationPanelMakeInternetRezervationButtonActionListener();
    addMainApplicationPanelShowVHSInformationButtonActionListener();
    addMainApplicationPanelShowDVDInformationButtonActionListener();
    addMainApplicationPanelShowInternetRezervationsActionListener();
    addMainApplicationPanelShowClientsInformationButtonActionListener();
    addMainApplicationPanelInsertClientButtonActionListener();
    addMainApplicationPanelInsertMovieButtonActionListener();
    addMainApplicationPanelInsertVHSButtonActionListener();
    addMainApplicationPanelInsertDVDButtonActionListener();
  }
});
```

}

On that main panel, I have a table which shows all the current medias. I want to be able to update that table via a search function.

The code for the search button action listener is:

```
private void addMainApplicationPanelSearchButtonActionListener() {
    graphicController.getMainApplicationPanel().addSearchButtonActionListener(new    ActionListener() {

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String[] columnNames = { "Media ID", "Title", "Pricipal Actors", "Type", "Duration", "Launch Date", "Price",
        "Status" };
    String title = graphicController.getMainApplicationPanel().getSearchTextField().getText();
    ResultSet resultSet = databaseLogicController.showParticularMediaInfo(title);
    String[][] data = parseMediaResultSet(resultSet, 8);

    graphicController.getMainApplicationPanel().setMediaTable(new JTable(data, columnNames));
    graphicController.getMainApplicationPanel().repaint();
    graphicController.getMainApplicationPanel().revalidate();
    graphicController.getMainFrame().repaint();
    graphicController.getMainFrame().revalidate();
  }
});
```

}

Now, I create a new table in the action listener based on the search criteria and set it in the main application panel, followed by calls to repaint and revalidate on both the main frame and the main panel. Why isn't the new table shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now, I create a new table in the action listener based on the search criteria

Don't create a new table. The easiest approach is to update the existing table with a new TableModel:

```
table.setModel(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommand you using this line

```
graphicController.getMainApplicationPanel().setMediaTable(new JTable(data, columnNames));
```

You can better get that table then `((DefaultTableModel)myTable.getModel()).setRowCount(0);` and `((DefaultTableModel)myTable.getModel()).addRow(new Object[]{data1, data2, ...});`

Comment: It gives me a ClassCastException;

Comment: What type of table model you are using? Cast to it

Comment: The thing is. I did not change, or have any code that changes the table model.

Comment: Try `myTable.setModel` method to replace the model with an entire new columns and rows